# How to open .pptx file with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, functional

Has anybody succeeded at opening Microsoft Powerpoint presentations using Jmeter? I need to open the specific `.pptx` file, convert it to a text file and then retrieve some strings using regular expressions.

Currently using HTTP Request where I provide a path to my local folder where the file resides. At View Tree Results selecting Documents to see the response. Copied `tika-app-1.15.jar` to the `Jmeter/lib` folder.

Getting:

> org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: TIKA-198: Illegal IOException from org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.PackageParser@5fa2a568

There may be some other options in getting the .pptx file? Please share your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the issue using the first PowerPoint document which search engine gave me [check here.](http://people.apache.org/~sctemme/ApconEU2008/Performance_Out.pptx)

Therefore I would recommend taking the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Save .pptx to a file using [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener and open it using Powerpoint or equivalent like [LibreOffice Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/). If it doesn't work - you won't be able to parse it with JMeter as well.
2. If you will be able to open the .pptx using Powerpoint or Impress and JMeter will fail to parse it - try downgrading to [Tika-app-1.14](https://tika.apache.org/1.14/index.html) as JMeter 3.2 comes with tika-core and tika-parsers versions 1.14 so it may be something connected with the versions mismatch. Don't forget to delete `tika-app-1.15.jar` from [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick the Tika jar app.
3. If point 3 doesn't help I would recommend reporting the issue to [JMeter Issue Tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) (first of all they will ask for .pptx file so be ready to present it)

See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article for more details on working with binary responses in JMeter tests.

Comment: Regarding #1 of your advice - I already have a file on my local in .pptx format and there is no need to Save Responses to a file functionality to be applied. I can open the file normally with PowepPoint app. Will try the second point you mention.

Comment: The file itself is 17MB long. So there might be a difficulty for Jmeter to read all of it and after I changed the tika-app-1.14.jar version now I see another error  org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser

Comment: Full log, please. If the file doesn't have confidential information you can also upload it somewhere so we could take a look

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the file because it's internal. But I see the logs: Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Failed to read the file input stream from file: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\apache-tika-4774077548978836627.tmp'  The second error is: Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Failed to read the zip entry source stream  The third error is Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Could not open the specified zip entry source stream